# Realm iOS Tutorial, Build iOS app from scratch, write failed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

I've followed the 'Build iOS app from scratch' tutorial on the realm website step by step and watched the video. Everything appears to be in order. Unfortunately the tutorial does not include the full source code for reference.

https://realm.io/docs/tutorials/realmtasks/

When I run the project it connects to the ROS and creates the realm without problem. I can see this in the realm browser and through a web browser.

However, it immediately starts throwing an error (in the Xcode console).

```
realmTask[1000:40858] Sync: Connection[1]: Connected to endpoint '127.0.0.1:9080' 
realmTask[1000:40858] Sync: Connection[1]: Writing failed: End of input
realmTask[1000:40858] Sync: Connection[1]: Connection closed due to error
```

The app does not crash, the error repeats over and over, and the app won't do anything.

Here is my setup code.

```
func setupRealm() {
    // Log in existing user with username and password
    let username = "abcdefg"  
    let password = "1234"  

    SyncUser.logIn(with: .usernamePassword(username: username, password: password, register: false), server: URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:9080")!) { user, error in
        guard let user = user else {
            fatalError(String(describing: error))
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Open Realm
            let configuration = Realm.Configuration(
                syncConfiguration: SyncConfiguration(user: user, realmURL: URL(string: "realm://127.0.0.1:9080/~/realmtasks")!)
            )
            self.realm = try! Realm(configuration: configuration)

            // Show initial tasks
            func updateList() {
                if self.items.realm == nil, let list = self.realm.objects(TaskList.self).first {
                    self.items = list.items
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            updateList()

            // Notify us when Realm changes
            self.notificationToken = self.realm.observe { _,_ in
                updateList()
            }
        }
    }
}

deinit {
    notificationToken?.invalidate()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for the confusion; we will be updating our tutorials as soon as possible.

Realm Cocoa 3.* requires the use of ROS 2.0, which is installed via NPM (instructions [here](https://realm.io/docs/get-started/installation/developer-edition/)). The version of Realm Object Server that comes from the zip file on our web site is ROS 1.0, and not compatible with Realm Cocoa 3.*.

If you wish to see the full source code for the demo project you can check out its [repository on GitHub](https://github.com/realm-demos/realm-tasks). You can clone that repository, install its CocoaPods, open the Xcode workspace, and build the project from source that way.